# Far 3, x64: Plugin for Secure FTP

Tags: far

Windows 10 (64 bit), Far. ver.3,  x64.

I can't find plugin for Secure FTP.
I need to connect by SSH to remote Linux Machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/michaellukashov/Far-NetBox

Check if you have `NetBox` already installed (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>):

[image]

To add a connection, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

[image]

I've also underlined the different tabs where one can change parameters, although usually the first tab is sufficient.